# javascript string and int

Tags: javascript

I came across some javascript code I don't understand:

what does `a < 5` mean if the variable `a` holds a string?

Thanks

Comment: ECMA Specs for JavaScript comparison http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a holds the string representation of a number, JavaScript will implicitly convert it to a number and perform the comparison.

Otherwise, it will return false.

For example:

```
var a = 'foo';
(a < 5) // will be false
(a > 5) // will be false

a = '10';

(a < 5) // will be false
(a > 5) // will be true
```

Comment: If a is null or undefined and other variations , refer  ECMA Specs for JavaScript comparison http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.3

Comment: Even if the string doesn't represent a number, it will be converted to Number, e.g. in your `var a = 'foo'` snippet, the string `'foo'` gets converted to `NaN`, and if one of the operands is `NaN` `false` is always the result.

Comment: Don't forget to mention truthy vs true, as exemplified in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883143/javascript-string-and-int/7883221#7883221).

Answer (score 0):

Same as if it held a number, due to JavaScript's (occasionally twisted) type conversion rules.

That said, code that *relies* on that always makes me a little twitchy; IMO it *should* be converted to a number manually so it can be sanity-checked under more-controlled conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = '5';
a   < 5;  // false
a   > 5;  // false
a  == 5;  // true
a === 5;  // false   <-- pay attention


var a = 5;
a   < 5;  // false
a   > 5;  // false
a  == 5;  // true
a === 5;  // true    <-- pay attention


var a = 'anythingelse';
a   < 5;  // false
a   > 5;  // false
a  == 5;  // false
a === 5;  // false
```